# Authentication session in safari with Firebase

Tags: facebook, firebase, session, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App that uses Firebase to authenticate users using facebook, you can check it in https://periodiza-dev.firebaseapp.com/.

The user interation works fine when using the safari in iPhone: the first login asks for email and password but the following accesses log automatically. The problem is when the user add the page to his homescreen and safari is initialized by this shortcut, the automatic login doesn't happen.

Comment: It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve here. Can you clarify?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope is more clear now. The problem is the automatic login when the page is added in the iPhone's homescreen.

Comment: Actually I think the problem is that the when the user is redirect to facebook to login the redirect to return opens the safari browser and not this separate view that works like an app. So the session that begun with the shortcut never receives the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using the wrong method to sign in with firebase.

Changed from

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

To

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) states that

> The redirect method is preferred on mobile devices.